# Find hidden network on windows 10 on Laptop HP Laptop 15S-fq1

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Hidden network has been applied by son and now we have tried everything to connect to home wifi with no luck.

- Have reset modem
- I have manual tried to add network by adding wifi name and wifi password.
- searched on google how to find hidden network, still no luck
- Windows 10 version 1909 on laptop
- Spoke to internet provider, preformed a heap of test, still not luck
- Spoke to HP helpdesk, they say they can not help to speak to the internet provider

I have spent so much time researching, trying to fix this problem and it driving me insane. Please help

Comment: Have you checked the "Connect to this network even if it hides its name/identity/SSID" box in your WiFi adapter properties?

Comment: It's not clear what has happened, or what you're trying to do. Has your son reconfigured the network to be hiddne? Has this laptop been connected to this network previously, or are you trying to connect for the first time? What errors or behaviour are you seeing? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1545283/edit) your question with these details.

Comment: When I run a windows network diagnostics troubleshoot report, I can see the wifi name under the detection details (diagnostics information (network Adapter)) - wireless connectivity. Its under list of visible access points - perferred networks. Under the subtitle of Connect even if network is not broadcaster: it says 'No' then under the subtitle of Connectable: It says No, Reason says ' 0x00028002.

Comment: As suggested by someone else, forget this network in Windows Settings: in WiFi, click on "Manage known networks", click on the line of the network in question in the list, and choose "Forget" (or "Dismiss", I don't remember; mine's in French), restart your PC, and try to connect again. If you're going to do it manually, make sure to choose the right security protocol in the wizard (should be WPA2-PSK or -Personal, but there might be other options too).

Comment: @Julianne Jarrett - did you try deleting the network profiles you do not need?

Answer (score 0):

Hidden wifi network means wifi just doesn't broadcast it's SSID. Loudly... :)

1. On laptop go to Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi, find your home network that you have added earlier and write down network name. Then click it and choose "Forget network"
2. If you actually reset modem, a default network should appear, like: TPLink123321, usually it's unencrypted network.
3. If you can reach your modem via LAN (with cable connected), then find out your router ip via "start" -> cmd, enter -> ipconfig

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Then connect to the address indicated and reconfigure wifi to your liking.

4. If none of this work, try to [add new wifi network](https://kb.netgear.com/30740/How-do-I-connect-to-a-hidden-network).

P.S. Of course I recommend to reboot laptop first, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Open an Admin Command Prompt, and type:

NETSH WLAN SHOW PROFILES   and enter

List the profiles. They will all be there. Now type:

NETSH WLAN DELETE PROFILE NAME="profile name" for any profile you do not want. Quotes around the name allow spaces in the name.